# docker compose mssql server setup

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, .net-8.0

I'd like to containerize my .NET 8 application. I'm using the Clean Architecture as structure of my project, and I let visual studio create the dockerfile for me:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Directory.Packages.props", "."]
COPY ["Directory.Build.props", "."]
COPY ["src/Web/Web.csproj", "src/Web/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./src/Web/./Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "./Web.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Web.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CCTemplate.Web.dll"]
```

Now that generated me a dockercompose file as well, but of course without sql server:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}web
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
```

I tried to add the db service, found many guides on the web, none worked. I even tried to add postgres as a last choice because I found video on YT with postgresql and dotnet 8, but didn't worked.

This was my last attemp I have done:

```
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

and this is the connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Database=valeart;User=sa;Password=Password123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=False"
  },
```

I didn't have Encrypt=false at the end, without that containers would run but I got that error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)'
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
```

With that it's not even compiling. I literally don't know anymore what to do to be honest. Any help on what I have to write inside dockercompose and most important inside the app.settings as DefaultConnection?

------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------
Nothing worked, tried with the string provided in the comment and with all the configuration provided by @datawookie.

The error now seems that the app can't connect to the database (even tho I can clearly see it running on my Docker Desktop app):

```
    1>NSwag command line tool for .NET Core Net80, toolchain v14.0.3.0 (NJsonSchema v11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))
1>Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
1>NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\Lavoro\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\14.0.3\tools\Net80
1>
1>Executing file 'config.nswag' with variables 'Configuration=Debug'...
1>Launcher directory: C:\Users\Lavoro\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\14.0.3\tools\Net80
1>fail: CCTemplate.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContextInitialiser[0]
1>      An error occurred while initialising the database.
1>      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
1>       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): Impossibile trovare il percorso di rete.
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
1>         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
1>      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>         at CCTemplate.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContextInitialiser.InitialiseAsync() in C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\DevOPS\ValeArt\backend\src\Infrastructure\Data\ApplicationDbContextInitialiser.cs:line 44
1>      ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
1>EXEC : warning Number: 53,State:0,Class:20
1>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
1> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))
1> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
1> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): Impossibile trovare il percorso di rete.
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at CCTemplate.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContextInitialiser.InitialiseAsync() in C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\DevOPS\ValeArt\backend\src\Infrastructure\Data\ApplicationDbContextInitialiser.cs:line 44
1>   at CCTemplate.Infrastructure.Data.InitialiserExtensions.InitialiseDatabaseAsync(WebApplication app) in C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\DevOPS\ValeArt\backend\src\Infrastructure\Data\ApplicationDbContextInitialiser.cs:line 19
1>   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\DevOPS\ValeArt\backend\src\Web\Program.cs:line 46
1>   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
1>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
1>ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
1>EXEC : warning Number: 53,State:0,Class:20
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at NSwag.Commands.ServiceProviderResolver.GetServiceProviderWithHostFactoryResolver(Assembly assembly) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/HostApplication.cs:line 170
1>   at NSwag.Commands.ServiceProviderResolver.GetServiceProvider(Assembly assembly) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/HostApplication.cs:line 70
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.Process(String commandContent, String outputFile, String applicationName) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.cs:line 27
1>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithFewArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
1>   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Launcher.Program.Main(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.AspNetCore.Launcher/Program.cs:line 132
1>System.InvalidOperationException: Swagger generation failed with non-zero exit code '1'.
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 195
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 270
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocument.cs:line 67
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 76
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 33
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 62
```

Comment: Try this connection string, using TrustServerCertificate=True instead of Encrypt=false "Server=db;Database=valeart;User=sa;Password=Password123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"

Comment: Aside... although it still works `SA_PASSWORD` has been deprecated for quite some time now (years?), switch to `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` before things start breaking.

Comment: Since `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 5 the [`Encrypt` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.encrypt) changed from `false,true` to a new enumerated type with `Mandatory,Strict,Optional` options. Have you tried adding `TrustServerCertificate=true` yet?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose.yml` (I'm mapping port 8080 on the `web` container since this is where my test API is being served).

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "CJnEmigeG!@JLipcRy4&2MNv"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

`Dockerfile` (For simplicity I removed the `publish` stage.)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["Directory.Packages.props", "."]
COPY ["Directory.Build.props", "."]
COPY ["src/Web/Web.csproj", "src/Web/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./src/Web/./Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/src/Web
RUN dotnet build "./Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CCTemplate.Web.dll"]
```

`appsettings.json` (I'm using the `tempdb` default database to test the connection.)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Database=tempdb;User=sa;Password=CJnEmigeG!@JLipcRy4&2MNv;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

`Program.cs` (This just creates a connection to the database.)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", async (HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    var dbContext = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    try
    {
        if (await dbContext.Database.CanConnectAsync())
        {
            return Results.Ok("Successfully connected to the database.");
        }
        else
        {
            return Results.Problem("Unable to connect to the database.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Results.Problem($"An error occurred while connecting to the database: {ex.Message}");
    }
});

await app.RunAsync();

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In the screenshot below you can see the Docker Compose stack running and a successful connection to the database reported in the browser.

[image]